# Why is this circuit making a short to ground?

Tags: breadboard

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnzuMJLZRdU&t=405s) video. I don't understand a circuit from the video works.

This is the circuit:

[image]

The last pin on the left is the reset pin, so every time the button is pressed, the microcontroller is reset.

I don't understand what is happening in the circuit when the button is pressed.

Why do the electrons coming from the negative side decide to go through the resistor instead of going through the microcontroller?

Comment: Don't worry about electrons. Just use conventional current which flows from + to -. Then you will speak the same language as all other electrical engineers.

Comment: I suggest that you stop thinking about electron flow from negative to positive. In the field of electronics we all think in the referential of conventional current from + to -. It doesn't matter if that convention is reversed or not. We all describe our thought in that referential. If you want to think in an electron point of view, you will have to convert everything you see in your reference frame.  It's an extra step. It will confuse you more and will complicate any discussion with any of us. Thus I suggest that you try to stick with the norm. It will be easier for you.

Comment: Welcome, Looking at your picture it is useless, it does not show anything. You have an advantage our eyes are not good enough to see your protype, you can. Try posting a schematic as it is wired, the whole circuit, not a frizzy thing. Show all connections, and links to technical information on all hardware devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pushing the button connects the reset pin directly to 0V ground node, which means that also the reset pin will have 0v, even if there is a 1 kohm resistor. Assuming that the other side of resistor is at 5V, then there is 5V over the resistor and thus 5mA will flow via resistor and button. If MCU pin has high impedance, i.e. no DC path to VCC, no current flows via MCU pin.